# Convert Date format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm

Tags: javascript, date

I request a API, this bellow format is not accept:

```
Thu Apr 12 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)
```

the

> "start_time":["Date format error. Please ues this type format：YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm[:ss[.uuuuuu]][+HH:MM|-HH:MM|Z]。"

---

part of my request:

Part of my request data:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="start_time"

Thu Apr 12 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)
------WebKitFormBoundaryPtZBgjhBEahHBOLY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="end_time"

Thu May 31 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)
```

---

I have two questions:

1. Does the `Thu Apr 12 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)` is one of the Date format? And then there is how many types of Date format?
2. How can I convert the example Date to this format `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm[:ss[.uuuuuu]][+HH:MM|-HH:MM|Z]`?

Comment: 1. Yes, it's date format. And no, it's not recognized by `Date` class parser. There is no finite number of formats, just some tools that has finite date formats (parser, that can recognize it). E.g. I can think of format `'97''12.01_14:59:12` (1997-01-12 12:59:14). It's not recognized by `Date` parser, but my parser recognizes it.

Comment: @244boy probably you are looking for this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: use momentjs javascript time ui script

Comment: @244boy it's in ISO 8601 format

Comment: Thank you, friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say how you get the string. If you have a Date object, you can use [*toISOString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring) to generate a timestamp in the required format. To answer your questions:

> Does the Thu Apr 12 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST) is one of the Date format?

No. The ECMAScript Date object is only required to parse the subset of ISO 8601 noted in the language specification, [ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date-time-string-format). Support for any other format is implementation dependent.

In general, you shouldn't rely on the built-in parser. It's much better to either write your own parser, or if you need to support a number of formats, use a library. There are plenty of good ones to choose from, but the bottom line is that you must know the timestamp format in order to be sure of correctly parsing it, whether you use a library or write your own parser.

> And then there is how many types of Date format?

A Date object doesn't have any format, it is simply a time value that represents a moment in time in UTC plus some fairly simplistic methods. The format of [*toString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.prototype.tostring) is implementation dependent, however [*toISOString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring) is compliant with ISO 8601. But to use it requires a Date object, so you'd have to parse the string to a Date to use it.

> How can I convert the example Date to this format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm[:ss[.uuuuuu]][+HH:MM|-HH:MM|Z]?

You can either parse it to a Date (using your own parser or a library) then use *toISOString* (or library equivalent), or just reformat the string, e.g.

```js
var s = 'Thu Apr 12 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)';

function toISOString(s) {
  var months = {jan:'01',feb:'02',mar:'03',apr:'04',may:'05',jun:'06',
                jul:'07',aug:'08',sep:'09',oct:'10',nov:'11',dec:'12'};
  var b = s.split(' ');

  return b[3] + '-' +
         months[b[1].toLowerCase()] + '-' +
         ('0' + b[2]).slice(-2) + 'T' +
         b[4] + b[5].substr(3);
}

console.log(toISOString(s));
```